# Check if looped dependency exists in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, loops, recursion, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I want to check if any loop exists in hierarchy in a table in sql.
(Example below.) It should return whether any loop is getting formed. When I tried a recursive cte it formed an infinite loop.

Data:

[image]

Comment: Can you add which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, Postgres etc) you are using and the SQL you already tried to the question?

Comment: In Postgres you can aggregate the "visited" items into an array and check the array in the join condition of the recursive CTE

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2. Can you please provide me the query?

Comment: @MarkBannister: MS SQL Server 2008 R2. Please help how do design an SQL query there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will list all Child elements from the data table, together with their parental hierarchy up to the point a circular reference is found (or where there are no more parents) and an indicator to show whether a circular reference was found in that Child's hierarchy:

```
with cte as
(select t.Child Original_Child, 
        t.Parent, 
        t.Child,
         '|' + convert(varchar(max),t.Parent) + '|' + convert(varchar(max),t.child) + '|' hierarchy_list, 
        convert(int,case Parent when Child then 1 else 0 end) circular_ind 
 from DataTable t
 union all
 select c.Original_Child, 
        t.Parent, 
        t.Child, 
        coalesce('|' + convert(varchar(max),t.Parent),'') + c.hierarchy_list hierarchy_list, 
        convert(int, 
                sign(charindex('|' + convert(varchar(max),t.parent) + '|',c.hierarchy_list)) 
                ) circular_ind
 from cte c
 join DataTable t on t.Child = c.Parent 
 where c.circular_ind=0),
cte_final as
(select c.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by original_child 
                           order by len(hierarchy_list) desc) rn from cte c)
select * from cte_final 
where rn=1
option (maxrecursion 0)
```